# Getting info on PCI slots

Tags: pci-express

According to Wikipedia, PCIe 2.0 has 500 MB/s per lane, twice the speed of PCIe 1.0.

Is there a way to tell what version are my slots?

Answer (score 2):

I’d check the documentation for your motherboard.

Comment: This; it's the easiest check.